# Legend of WMS-Group Layer

Tags: wms, legend, group-layer

I have a group layer and I want to show the legend of all layers in this group layer.

[image]

For one layer in this group I get the Legend with this url: `GEOSERVER/KRE_KANAL/ows?service=WMS&request=GetLegendGraphic&format=image/png&width=20&height=20&layer=onelayer`.

Now I want to get a legend for all layers in the group. I read here, that this is possible: https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/get_legend_graphic/index.html

But I do not get a legend image. I tried:

`GEOSERVER/KRE_KANAL/ows?service=WMS&request=GetLegendGraphic&format=image/png&width=20&height=20&layer=KRE_KANAL`
and 
`GEOSERVER/KRE_KANAL/ows?service=WMS&request=GetLegendGraphic&format=image/png&width=20&height=20&layer=KRE_KANAL:KRE_KANAL`

But all the time I get the error

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><!DOCTYPE ServiceExceptionReport SYSTEM "http://172.16.206.128:8080/geoserver/schemas/wms/1.1.1/WMS_exception_1_1_1.dtd"> <ServiceExceptionReport version="1.1.1" >   <ServiceException>
      java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown font Dingbats
Unknown font Dingbats
</ServiceException></ServiceExceptionReport>
```

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server (Linux?) does not have the font Dingbats installed, as the error says: `Unknown font Dingbats`.

Comment: Thank you very much. You're right. The error message stated it. I was sure that this font is not used. Now I've checked it again and it was actually used in a style.